# programmatically Set Id of button and TextView and perform operation based on id

Tags: java, android

I'm try to setId of button and textview and then try to setlayout_below of textview under the button . but can't work my code and show error :

```
Button btnMakeObjectRequest=new Button(this);
        btnMakeObjectRequest.setText("Get JSON");
        btnMakeObjectRequest.setId(1);
     TextView   txtResponse = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,1);
        txtResponse.setLayoutParams(lp);

        rl.addView(btnMakeObjectRequest);
        rl.addView(txtResponse);

        setContentView(rl);
```

Comment: can't run program show red warning as compilation error at
 btnMakeObjectRequest.setId(1); 
this line under "1" . @Pztar

Answer (score 2):

You should assign the view a unique id using View.generateViewId() method. Be aware this is for API 17+

```
btnMakeObjectRequest.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

Then when you need the id just call

```
btnMakeObjectRequest.getId();
```